# Display Comment Form on dedicated Page for each post

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

I have the following requirement to complete and i didn't figure out how to do it.

Inside a post, for each post, to call comment form on a dedicated page, in dedicated page  the user post a comment and then is redirected to the initial post on submit.

in single.php
i need to call comments_template() but to extract only the comments results without comment_form()
then
when a user wants to post something, calls a page (comment_page) where comment_form() is included, the comment_form extracts from session postID and other parameters which allows that a comment is right inserted into the specific post

So far i manage to insert the comment form into a modal window(JS) but is not a friendly option.

Thanx

Comment: [Is this one answer you](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105531/how-to-display-comments-on-different-page)?

Comment: It's better to talk with code at hands. Can you [edit] the Question and add more details?